# How to create custom endpoint to insert to database in directus cms

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, directus

im using directus CMS and need to create custom CRUD endpoints, the docs show only how to retrieve data.

i was able to retrieve the data as the example described on the official doc, i hope somebody can help implement all CRUD operations.

Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

What aspect of the API's CRUD docs didn't work for you?

For example, creating an item (database record) in the REST API is as simple as POSTing JSON to the `/items/:collection` URL for that collection (database table):

```
POST /items/articles

{
    "title": "Hello world!",
    "body": "This is our first article"
}
```

https://docs.directus.io/reference/items.html#create-an-item

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but i'm asking for custom endpoints like this one [ custom get endpoint ] (https://docs.directus.io/extensions/endpoints.html#example-recipes)